# Find dynamically created tab controls inside placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webusercontrol

I have an aspx page, in which I have used a PlaceHolder control to contain dynamically created ajax tabconatiner, i.e the no of tabs in the tab container are decided at run time based on some quantity. Each tab in turn loads an ascx user control The code is as follows:

ASPX Code:

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PC1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        createTab();
        AddControl();
    }
}

private void createTab()
{
    try
    {
        tbcDynamic = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
        for (int i = 0; i < DOQuantity; i++)
        {
            int tabno = i;
            TabPanel tbpanelProcessCategory = new TabPanel();
            tbpanelProcessCategory.HeaderText = "BeneficiaryDetails" + " " + (i + 1);
            tbpanelProcessCategory.ID = "Tab" + tabno.ToString();
            //tbpanelProcessCategory.BorderStyle = 0;
            tbpanelProcessCategory.Attributes["class"] = "ajax__tab_body";
            tbcDynamic.Tabs.Add(tbpanelProcessCategory);
            //tbpanelProcessCategory.Controls.Add()
        }
    }
 private void AddControl()
 {
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DOQuantity; i++)
        {
            Control ctrlNombre = LoadControl("beneDetail.ascx");
            tbcDynamic.Tabs[i].Controls.Add(ctrlNombre);
            //tbcDynamic.Style.Add("border", "0");
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)

            PC1.Controls.Add(tbcDynamic);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

User Control:

```
//Contains usual text boxes
```

Sorry for my poor formatting :(.

Comment: This is exactly what u need [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591756/get-values-from-dynamically-added-textboxes-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: @Khazrabtek: Thanks for sharing the link..although i am a bit confused about the parent child controls here...

Comment: So my page aspx page has placeholder "PC1"  in which I add a dynamically created tab container and then. Each tabcontainer contains a user control in turn.