# How to get the value of dynamic textbox values?

Tags: asp.net

I have created two functions, one for dynamically adding the textboxes into the table and the other is to insert the values in the database. I am having trouble with getting the id of the dynamic textbox and inserting its text into the database. So far I have tried creating a list to save the id of the textbox but the values are blank.

**ASPX**

```
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Set numbers from 1-30" ID="tbxRows" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="30" ControlToValidate="tbxRows" runat="server"></asp:RangeValidator>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" Cssclass="btn green" runat="server" Text="Set Rows" style="width:100%;" />


                <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                   <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            Departure Airport
                        </asp:TableCell>
                       <asp:TableCell>
                            Departure Date
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            Departure Time (UTC)
                        </asp:TableCell>
                       <asp:TableCell>
                            Arrival Airport
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            Arrival Date
                        </asp:TableCell>
                       <asp:TableCell>
                            Arrival Time (UTC)
                        </asp:TableCell>
                   </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn green" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

**ASPX.cs**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int numrows = Convert.ToInt32(tbxRows.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < numrows; i++) { 
        ScheduleFlights newSF = new ScheduleFlights()
        {
            ACnumber = tbxACreg.Text,
            Flightnumber = tbxFlightNo.Text,
            depport = "row" + i + "tbx" + 0.Text,
            depdate = "row" + i + "tbx" + 1.Text,
            deptime = "row" + i + "tbx" + 2.Text,
            arrport = "row" + i + "tbx" + 3.Text,
            arrdate = "row" + i + "tbx" + 4.Text,
            arrtime = "row" + i + "tbx" + 5.Text,

        };
        new ScheduleFlightsDC().CreateFlights(newSF);



        
        };
        successLabel.Visible = true;
        successLabel.InnerHtml = "Schedule Created Successfully";
            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        warningLabel.Visible = true;
        warningLabel.InnerHtml = "Error";
    }
}


protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxRows.Text)) {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(tbxRows.Text) < 30 && Convert.ToInt32(tbxRows.Text) > 0)
            {
                // Generate rows and cells.           
                int numrows = Convert.ToInt32(tbxRows.Text);
                int numcells = 6;
                for (int j = 0; j < numrows; j++)
                {
                    TableRow r = new TableRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < numcells; i++)
                    {
                        TextBox txtNewTextBox = new TextBox();
                        txtNewTextBox.ID = "row" + j + "tbx" + i;
                        txtNewTextBox.CssClass = "form-control";
                        TableCell c = new TableCell();
                        c.Controls.Add(txtNewTextBox);
                        r.Cells.Add(c);
                    }
                    Table1.Rows.Add(r);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                warningLabel.Visible = true;
                warningLabel.InnerHtml = "Error! Field not within 1 to 30";
            }
    }
    else
    {
        warningLabel.Visible = true;
        warningLabel.InnerHtml = "Error! Field Empty";
    }
}
```

I have referred to these guides as well but the solutions provided did not work. [get values from dynamically added textboxes asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591756/get-values-from-dynamically-added-textboxes-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you create the dynamically added rows/textboxes on postbacks like described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531004/how-to-get-the-value-of-dynamic-textbox-values)?
But even if you do that right, this will not work with your code, since you can't access the textboxes like you try: `"row" + i + "tbx" + 0.Text` - does this even compile?

Try to iterate over your table rows in the submit like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Table1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    TableRow row = Table1.Rows[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++) 
    {
        TableCell cell = row.Cells[j];
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)cell.FindControl("row" + i + "tbx" + j);
    }
}
```

So you can gather all the data you want to save in your database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however the textbox seem to give me a null value and the for loop for the table1.rows looped once.

Comment: It will give you null if you don't create the dynamically added rows/textboxes on postbacks every time.

Comment: How do i add the row/textboxes on postback? I looked up online to search how to do it but I do not know how to apply it to the code

Comment: you should read the question/answer you posted in your starting-question. From there you can get the information you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591756/get-values-from-dynamically-added-textboxes-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Managed to get the code working. Thanks for helping me out!